# Find position value of node with limited functions of tree - Java

Tags: java, tree

Ok so I have a bit of a unique issue. So a sub part of an issue i'm having is to just get the value of a parent node of a tree. But there is no getPosition or getValue like function.

The only functions that are available for this section are:

1. Tree.parent(p) -> takes an position - returns the position of the parent of p
2. Tree.children(p) -> which takes a position argument also but spits out a string list of it's children

--Edit: position is a position in the tree you feed it.

I'm trying to work out how I can get the value (the contents of the node) of a parent node when the only way to get the value out of anything is by using the children method which prints out the values of the parent node and how to ID the right one. I assume it has to do with going a level up and getting it's parents possibly? But it's got my mind a bit warped.

P.S To start my traversal i'm just doing tree.children(0) - the root.

Edit2: The type of the tree is:

```
Tree<String> tree
```

- not sure if this helps and the only imports of the file are:

import adt.*;

import java.util.*;

The Tree has the following functions:

package adt;

```
import java.util.*;

/**
 * An interface for a tree. A tree may contain zero or more nodes.
 * 
 * - taken and adapted from Goodrich, Tamassia and Goldwasser (6th Ed)
 * 
 * @param <E>, the type of the objects to be stored in the tree.
 * 
 */
public interface Tree<E> {

    /**
     * Returns the number of nodes in the tree.
     * 
     * @return number of nodes in the tree
     */
    int size();

    /**
     * Tests whether the tree is empty.
     * 
     * @return true if the tree is empty, false otherwise
     */
    boolean isEmpty();

    /**
     * Returns the root Position of the tree (or null if tree is empty).
     * 
     * @return root Position of the tree (or null if tree is empty)
     */
    Position<E> root();

    /**
     * Returns the Position of p's parent (or null if p is root).
     *
     * @param p
     *            A valid Position within the tree
     * @return Position of p's parent (or null if p is root)
     * @throws IllegalArgumentException
     *             if p is not a valid Position for this tree.
     */
    Position<E> parent(Position<E> p) throws IllegalArgumentException;

    /**
     * Returns an iterable collection of the Positions representing p's
     * children.
     * 
     * NOTE: For efficiency reasons, the list of returned children may be part
     * of the internal state of the tree, and so must not be modified. The
     * internal consistency of the tree, and its future behaviour are not
     * defined if the list of children returned by this method is modified.
     *
     * @param p
     *            A valid Position within the tree
     * @return iterable collection of the Positions of p's children
     * @throws IllegalArgumentException
     *             if p is not a valid Position for this tree.
     */
    List<Position<E>> children(Position<E> p) throws IllegalArgumentException;

    /**
     * Returns the number of children of Position p.
     *
     * @param p
     *            A valid Position within the tree
     * @return number of children of Position p
     * @throws IllegalArgumentException
     *             if p is not a valid Position for this tree.
     */
    int numChildren(Position<E> p) throws IllegalArgumentException;

    /**
     * Returns true if Position p represents the root of the tree.
     *
     * @param p
     *            A valid Position within the tree
     * @return true if p is the root of the tree, false otherwise
     */
    boolean isRoot(Position<E> p);

    /**
     * Returns true if Position p has one or more children.
     *
     * @param p
     *            A valid Position within the tree
     * @return true if p has at least one child, false otherwise
     * @throws IllegalArgumentException
     *             if p is not a valid Position for this tree.
     */
    boolean isInternal(Position<E> p) throws IllegalArgumentException;

    /**
     * Returns true if Position p does not have any children.
     *
     * @param p
     *            A valid Position within the tree
     * @return true if p has zero children, false otherwise
     * @throws IllegalArgumentException
     *             if p is not a valid Position for this tree.
     */
    boolean isExternal(Position<E> p) throws IllegalArgumentException;

}
```

Comment: Added edits to try and explain it.

Comment: Show your code please.

Comment: The answer lies in how you traverse the entire tree (not just the root) using this restricted API.

Comment: I'm not sure if this helps - the tree is of type Tree<String> tree but i'm not sure where it's being referenced from since the only imports of the file are from:import adt.*;

import java.util.*;

Comment: Can you show the code for `Position<E>`?

Comment: The "value" is the `String` contained at the node, then. So it must be that a `Position<String>` has a method in it for retrieving the value of the `String` stored in it; otherwise, there's something wrong with the `Position` class.